# CNN in Keras: unexpected drop of accuracy for small batch sizes

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a problem with a simple CNN (based on a sample script from `Keras` Github repo) with which I tried to replicate (with Keras) an experiment in Chapter 6 of Michael Nielsen's online book on deep learning (in which he used plain Theano). I used his hyperparameters, i.e. `batch_size = 10` and `nb_epoch = 60`, but relu instead of sigmoid as activation function. His implementation achieved an accuracy of 99.06%. To my surprise, the accuracy with my program was below 10%, and to my further surprise, it was reasonably > 98% when I used `batch_size = 15` or greater (I tried both `Tensorflow` and `Theano`). For the Python code see this [link](https://slack-files.com/T0QKJHQRE-F4FGCDQ0J-f72598a1ea).
Is there any problem with my code or is this a "feature" of `Keras`?

Comment: [The paper "Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf) may be an interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

The `batch_size` you use is really small. Moreover - you are not using any additional optimizer features (like e.g. `momentum`) which could really harm your training in this case. To understand what the most possibly happen try to understand what is actually happening in case of your training:

1. Every training procedure wants to decrease an error on your training set **X** in order to do this you are computing a gradient of the error on this dataset w.r.t. to parameters and then - change them in the direction which would make your error smaller.
2. Computing the gradient on a whole dataset might be really costly - so instead of that - optimizer computes the approximation of this gradient on a part of dataset (called `batch` of size `batch_size`) and uses this to change parameters.
3. Now try to imagine that you have a small percentage of your samples misclassified - or really weird cases which makes gradient to point in different direction than most of samples would do. In this case - when the `batch_size` is small - this could make this *outliers* to impact more on your training. In case of bigger batches - this impact is smoothed by the *normal* samples.
4. Your network is relatively shallow - it's belived and empirically proven - that such networks might suffer from so called *poor minimas* where your network stuck in a region - where every change would increase the error (backpropagation is not working in this case) - and even randomization couldn't move your parameters from this region. In case when your training is much more chaotic - the probability that you'll end up in a *poor minimum* tends to be greater.

It's not so suprising that increasing the `batch_size` made your network better. In order to prevent your network from downsides of a *vanilla gradient descent* with a small `batch_size` you may also try `momentum` (with `nesterov`) or increase the depth of your network to the `size >> 5` as it's belived that such networks suffer less from *poor minimas*.

Comment: I understand the point that the `batch_size`could be too small. However, I do not understand the difference between the results using a `Keras` and a pure `Theano` implementation, respectively.

Comment: You could try to restart your training a couple of times. Maybe it's due to the fact that `keras` is shuffling a dataset during training.